word choice: [take/endure/tolerate horror]
I have made up the sentences below.
(1a) Bill asked, "Is the new ghost story very scary?" John replied, "It's difficult to say. It depends on how well you can take horror."
(1b) Bill asked, "Is the new ghost story very scary?" John replied, "It's difficult to say. It depends on how well you can endure horror."
(1c) Bill asked, "Is the new ghost story very scary?" John replied, "It's difficult to say. It depends on how well you can tolerate horror."
Which word choice is correct? Thank you.

It's not a question of 'which is correct', but 'which is most suitable'. None of them is 'wrong'.

Take is the most natural among the three; endure and tolerate are more for pain or similar kind of discomfort which you may be able to handle just for a certain period.
Take is more versatile and is good also for horror, the type you either take it or fail to take it.

Out of the three, take is more sort of the standard usage for everyday scenarios. Either could work depending on the context, although I'd say tolerate sounds somewhat unusual here.
Handle and stomach are two other alternatives worth considering that I can think of. Phrases with them are also fairly common in everyday use.
